# In jquery.balloon.js tip disappears setting offsetX

Tags: jquery, balloon

I am using library jquery.balloon.js, it works fine in general but I have a problem.

When i set the value e.g. "offsetX: 10" the tip disappears.
With "offsetY" there are no problems.

Do you experience the same issue? Have you found a solution ?

-] After a comment I add the widget code

```
$('document').ready(function() {
   var cssStyle2 = {
      zIndex: '2000',
      border: 'solid 0px #5baec0',
      padding: '10px',
      fontSize: '80%',
      opacity: '1',
      backgroundColor: 'grey',
      boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px #555',
      color: 'white'
      };
  var balData = {     
      html: true,
      contents: `<div style='width:200px'>  <span style='font-size:95%;'> 
      FOO BAR BAZ 
      </span> 
      </div>
      `, 
     tipSize: 7,
     // offsetY: 15,
    // offsetX: 10,
    css: cssStyle2
    }
    var shown = false;
    $('#framePerLegendaGrafico').on("click","#spanNoteGraficoRendim",    function() {
    console.log(" --> chiamato ballon su note" + shown);
    shown ? $(this).hideBalloon() : $(this).showBalloon( balData );
    shown = !shown;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Given information is not enough to help, may be other styles around your html element causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, I can will add the widget code. The page itself is very complex I can't describe it here.